# Java's private field access

Tags: java

I'm having diffuculties understanding why I can access a private field outside the *this.* context?
To clarify I have added a small *MyClass example:*

```
public class MyClass {

    private int myPrivateInt;

    public MyClass(int myPrivateInt) {
        this.myPrivateInt = myPrivateInt;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // if it's not an instance of MyClass it's obviously not equal
        if (!(obj instanceof MyClass)) return false;
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) obj;

        // here comes the part I don't quite understand fully:
        // why can I access a private field outside of the "this." context?
        return this.myPrivateInt == myClass.myPrivateInt;
    }
}
```

Is this a delibarate language choice or is it simply not possible to distinguish between the *this.* context and (more or less) "the same class" that is passed into the *equals(Object obj)* method?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the implications of `private`. It does not limit access to `this`, it limits access to *any* code in `MyClass`. So anything in `MyClass` can access it, even if it's from a different instance of a `MyClass`.

You would *not* be able to access it outside of `MyClass`, e.g.:

```
public class MyClass {

    private int myPrivateInt;

    public void example (MyClass m) {
        int x = m.myPrivateInt; // <- OK, we are in MyClass 
    }        

}

public class SomewhereElse {

    public void example (MyClass m) {
        int x = m.myPrivateInt; // <- not allowed
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, I think I'm kind of on my way grasping it. But then again, is it good practice to use it like this or would it be better to go with getters and setters anyway?

Comment: @baeda That *really* depends on your situation. Using getters allows subclasses to override non-final getters and in some situations that is helpful. Getters are also useful when the value in question may require some computation to obtain. But for your basic example, the use of that private `int` seems sufficient. Generally, good practice is to use whatever leads to the clearest, cleanest, most maintainable code that meets your requirements. As an exercise, try writing a version with getters and one without, and see which one works out better. That's a big question to answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, you are cheking first that the object you received is of `MyClass` type

by checking following

```
obj instanceof MyClass
```

then if it is, you are checking if that object has the same property value as `MyClass` by checking following

```
this.myPrivateInt == myClass.myPrivateInt;//here you are not accessing it from outside but just comparing value of `MyClass` object property(`myPrivateInt`) to the `Object` you passed
```

if it is having same property value you are returning `true` else `false`

so here goes step by step description for `equals`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //you are cheking if the Object you passed is of MyClass type(means it is either MyClass object or any Child of MyClass)
        if (!(obj instanceof MyClass)) return false;
//if not return false directly, or just cast Object to MyClass(as you know it is MyClass type so it can be casted to MyClass and will not give any cast exception)
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) obj;

        //here you are checking if the object you passed(which is supposed to contain properties MyClass has, so myClass object will also have myPrivateInt variable/property)
//you are just comparing that value to current MyClass object's myPrivateInt property
//if that also is equal, you can say both objects are equal
        return this.myPrivateInt == myClass.myPrivateInt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access any private members of references of type `MyClass` if this access occurs within the body of `MyClass` itself.

Based on [JLS 6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) *Determining accessibility* (Excerpt) :

> A member of a reference type is
>   accessible only if the type is accessible and the member
>   is declared to permit access:
>
> ....... if the member is declared private, then access
>   is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level
>   class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member.

Hope that helps